# How to pass string variable inside stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, insert

Hi I am working on stored procedure. In this stored procedure I am inserting data in one table. But in that insert statement I am also using select statement just to get id of another table just for optimization purpose. But in that select statement I am passing string variable for comparison and I am getting following error

```
Error: ER_CANT_AGGREGATE_2COLLATIONS: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='
```

My table structure where I am inserting data is as follows:

```
table name : user_data
Columns:

user_data_id : INT PK
user_id: INT
country_id : INT
state_id : INT
city_id: INT
 created_date: DATETIME
```

Also table structure of country, state and city master tables are as follows:

```
table name : country_master 
columns:

country_master_id : INT PK
name: VARCHAR(100)

table name : state_master
columns:

state_master_id : INT PK
name: VARCHAR(100)

table name : city_master
columns:

city_master_id : INT PK
 name: VARCHAR(100)
```

My stored procedure which is having issue is as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_saveData`(IN userId INT, IN countryName VARCHAR(100), IN stateName VARCHAR(100), IN cityName VARCHAR(100), IN createdDate DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_data(user_id, country_id, state_id, city_id, created_date)
    VALUES (
        userId,
        (SELECT mst_country_id FROM mst_country WHERE name=countryName), 
        (SELECT mst_state_id FROM mst_state WHERE name=stateName), 
        (SELECT mst_city_id FROM mst_city WHERE name=cityName),
        createdDate)
    ;
END
```

I have tried using following way.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_saveData`(IN userId INT, IN countryName VARCHAR(100), IN stateName VARCHAR(100), IN cityName VARCHAR(100), IN createdDate DATETIME)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_data(user_id, country_id, state_id, city_id, created_date)
    VALUES (
        userId,
        (SELECT mst_country_id FROM mst_country WHERE name=@countryName), 
        (SELECT mst_state_id FROM mst_state WHERE name=@stateName), 
        (SELECT mst_city_id FROM mst_city WHERE name=@cityName),
        createdDate)
    ;
END
```

In this case I am not getting above error but its inserting null values in `country_id`, `city_id` and `state_id` columns.

Please help me in this. I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify COLLATE option in the comparing expression explicitly.

Comment: *I have tried using following way.* Investigate the difference between user-defined variables and local (including compound statement parameters) variables.

Comment: As for the `COLLATION` issue, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'col%';`

Answer (score 0):

Over-normalization.  There is essentially no advantage and some potential disadvantages to normalizing city, state, and country.

I do suggest using the 2-byte standard

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

for countries.

Comment: Actually problem is we cant use country_code. Because we are using google places API and they are returning country, state and city names. So we need to match with names only.